# Reading file and store in vector

Tags: java

I'm reading from the file:

name1 wordx wordy passw1 
name2 wordx wordy passw2 
name3 wordx wordy passw3 
name (i) wordx wordy PASSW (i) 
x 
x word
x words
words
x
words

At the moment I can print line by line:

Line 1: name1 wordx wordy passw1 
Line 2: name2 wordx wordy passw2

I plan to have access to:
users [0] = name1 
users [1] = name2 
users [2] = name3 
..

passws [0] = passw1 
passws [1] = passw2 
passws [2] = passw3 
..

My code is:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    Scanner inFile = null;
    try {
        inFile = new Scanner(new File("C:\\file.txt"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    while (inFile.hasNextLine()) {
        list.add(inFile.nextLine()+",");
    }

    String listString = "";
    for (String s : list) {
        listString += s + "\t";
    }

    String[] parts = listString.split(",");
    System.out.println("Line1: "+ parts[0]);
}
```

How do I get the following output:

> User is name1 and password is passw1 
>   User is name32 and password is passw32

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you're *saying* you use an array, you have *code* that uses a list, and you really *should* be using a map.

Comment: "How do I get the following output" that does not seem to be about *reading* the file at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this will do:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    Scanner inFile = null;
    try {
        inFile = new Scanner(new File("C:\\file.txt"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    while (inFile.hasNextLine()) {
        list.add(inFile.nextLine());
    }

    int line = 0;
    String[] parts = list.get(line).split(" ");
    String username = parts[0];
    String pass = parts[3]; 
    System.out.println("Line" + (line + 1) + ": " + "User is " + username +" and password is " + pass);
}
```

EDIT: if you want to iterate through all lines just put last lines in a loop:

```
for (int line = 0; line < list.size(); line++) {
    String[] parts = list.get(line).split(" ");
    String username = parts[0];
    String pass = parts[3];
    System.out.println("Line" + (line + 1) + ": " + "User is " + username +" and password is " + pass);
}
```

Comment: how do I do this automatically so if I want to print the line 30?
User is name30 and password is passw30

Comment: Just change line:
     `int line = 30;`

Comment: Ok. When I use for code after run file I got: "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3" at String pass = parts[1];

Comment: Interesting, why does it say array has no index 3, in this line of code the only index used is 1.

Comment: If i have name1 passw1 at the first line and in others it works. But if i have name1 anyword anyword2 passw1 at the first line doesnt work.

Comment: Sure it won't. If you have a different file layout, you should specify it in the question.

Comment: You really help me, but I realized that the output was not what I thought.

Comment: I edited the question.I asked the question wrongly.Im so sorry

Comment: I have edited the code so that it takes the last word as password.

Comment: parts[length - 1] didnt work but no problem parts[3] works.
My problem is that have some lines that doesnt have 4 strings.

Comment: And which word is the password?

Comment: Fourth word. Ex: user32 anyword anyword2 password.
After the last user i have so many line but im not interested

Comment: After the last user I have specific char. Error: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3; its because exists lines that didnt have 4 strings. I think. How i can solve?

Comment: Break from the loop when you have that char.

Comment: Inside "the for" after declaration of parts. Do break if (parts.equals('#')) ?

Comment: like `if ("#".equals(list.get(line))) break;`

Comment: Thats it. I want to print users[9] and password[9]. I created a array list users and convert to string but didnt work. Do you have any sugestion?

Comment: Why did you convert the array list of users into a string?
The basic steps are:
1) Read each line into String element in ArrayList<String> list
2) Loop through the lines parsing out username and password
3) Print them out.

Comment: I agree. But after this code that we discuss i can got:
System.out.println("User is " + user[7] + "password is " + pass[7]); ?

Comment: In my code, there are no user and pass arrays. These are plain Strings that are updated inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to do is, to add this loop to the end of your code :

```
for(int i = 0; i <= parts.length(); i++){
     System.out.println("parts["+i+"] :" + parts[i] );
}
```

that will simply show the result of the split using `,`.

Then adapt your code, you may want to use another regex to `split()` your lines, for instance a space.

```
 String[] parts = listString.split(" ");
```

for documentation about `split()` method check [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use a `java.util.Map`, a standard API which allows you to *store objects and read each one of them* by a key. (In your case, string objects indexed by string keys). Example:

Let's assume this empty map:

```
Map<String, String> map=new HashMap<String,String>();
```

If you store this:

```
map.put("month", "january");
map.put("day", "sunday");
```

You can expect that `map.get("month")` will return "january", `map.get("day")` will return "sunday", and `map.get(any-other-string)` will return `null`.

Back to your case: First, you must create and populate the map:

```
private Map<String, String> toMap(Scanner scanner)
{
    Map<String, String> map=new HashMap<String, String>();
    while (scanner.hasNextLine())
    {
        String line=scanner.nextLine();
        String[] parts=line.split(" ");

        // Validation: Process only lines with 4 tokens or more:
        if (parts.length>=4)
        {
            map.put(parts[0], parts[parts.length-1]);
        }
    }
    return map;
}
```

And then, to read the map:

```
private void listMap(Map<String,String> map)
{
    for (String name : map.keySet())
    {
        String pass=map.get(name);
        System.out.println(...);
    }
}
```

You must include both in your class and call them from the `main` method.

Comment: I edited the question. I asked the question wrongly.

Comment: The file may contain more than 3 users.I dont know the number.

Comment: No, no. Don't get it wrong: My algorithm reads *all* the lines from the file, but only processes those whith 4 of more tokens (which is the leading rule I've learnt from the format you have explained).

Comment: Exactly, you are right. How i can print users[9] password[9]?users.get(9)+passwords.get(9)?

Comment: With the solution I've proposed, there is no need to index by integers. The method listMap browses all the contents read from the file. Do you *really* need to index by arbitrary integers?

Comment: I am not sure.
I'll need after the list of users and make correspondence with the password. Be able to search by the user and the respective pass.

Comment: Well, look at my next answer. And try to struggle with it a little: You'll understand it soon.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get that output then this should do the trick:

```
    public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

    Scanner inFile = null;
    try {
        inFile = new Scanner(new File("F:\\file.txt"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Map<String, String> userAndPassMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    while (inFile.hasNextLine()) {
        String nextLine = inFile.nextLine();
        String[] userAndPass = nextLine.split(" ");
        userAndPassMap.put(userAndPass[0], userAndPass[1]);
    }

    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : userAndPassMap.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println("User is:" +  entry.getKey() + " and password is:" + entry.getValue());
    }
}
```

By storing in a map you are linking directly each username with its password. If you need to save them into separate arrays then you can do this in the while loop instead:

```
List<String> users = new LinkedList<>(),passwords = new LinkedList<>();
    while (inFile.hasNextLine()) {
        String nextLine = inFile.nextLine();
        String[] userAndPass = nextLine.split(" ");
        users.add(userAndPass[0]);
        passwords.add(userAndPass[1]);
    }
```

and later transform them to arrays

```
users.toArray()
```

Comment: I edited the question. I asked the question wrongly.

Answer (score 0):

If you need arbitraray indexing of the read lines, use ArrayList:

First, define a javabean User:

```
public class User
{
    private String name;
    private String password;
    // ... add full constructor, getters and setters.
}
```

And then, you must create and populate the list:

```
private ArrayList<User> toList(Scanner scanner)
{
    List<User> list=new ArrayList<User>();
    while (scanner.hasNextLine())
    {
        String line=scanner.nextLine();
        String[] parts=line.split(" ");

        // Validation: Process only lines with 4 tokens or more:
        if (parts.length>=4)
        {
            list.add(new User(parts[0], parts[parts.length-1]));
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```